# Почему contains не находит вложенный массив в списке?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Результат должен быть true, в чем ошибка?

```
List<Integer[]> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
for(int r = 0; r < 64; r++) {
    
    Integer block[] = {1,2};
    blocks.add(block);
    
}
Integer[] xy1 = {1,2};
System.out.println(blocks.contains(xy1));
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, в ответе привести пример рабочего кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому при проверке наличия массива через метод `contains` равенство массивов (в отличие от равенства списков) проверяется по равенству ссылок (условно - по равенству адреса в памяти), как при сравнении объектов через `==`, а не `equals`.

Чтобы массивы оказались равны, они должны быть одним и тем же массивом. У вас массивы созданные в цикле - это не тот же самый массив, наличие которого вы проверяете, поэтому `contains` и не находит его.

Если бы у вас был список списков, то все бы работало, т.к. равенство списков проверяется по равенству их элементов. Проще всего так и сделать: заменить вложенные массивы на списки.

Вносим минимальные изменения в код, и все волшебным образом начинает работать:

```
List<List<Integer>> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
for(int r = 0; r < 64; r++) {
    
    List<Integer> block = List.of(1,2);
    blocks.add(block);
    
}
List<Integer> xy1 = List.of(1,2);
System.out.println(blocks.contains(xy1));
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Vp61LRLh1Q